# Passing array from controller to view and show it

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

### I am new with codeigniter.I want to send an array from controller to view and show it.but this error was show in view:

```
A PHP error was encountered   
Severity:Notice  
Message:Undefined variable:pub   
Filename:views/first.php  
Line number:25
```

this is my code :
*Cotroller*

```
$data['pub']=$this->mymodel->get_public();
$this->load->view('first',$data);
```

*Model*

```
function pub_article()
   {
        $where=array('public'=>'1');
         $query=$this->db->get_where('article',$where);
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
           return $query->result();
        else
          return false;
   }
```

*View*

```
foreach($pub->result() as $row){
echo "<p>".$row->tiltl."</p>"
}
```

Comment: your model may not return any result.

Comment: var_dump($data['pub']);

Comment: Is it returning more that one record in the $query->result?

Comment: @Jason Small yes it returns more than one record

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

In model:

```
$where=array('public'=>'1');
$query=$this->db->get_where('article',$where);
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
   return $query;
else
   return false;
```

In your view:

```
if($pub!=false)
{
  foreach($pub->result() as $row){
   echo "<p>".$row->tiltl."</p>"
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code.It returns false.I change my query like this: $this->db->query("select * from article where public='1'").It shows the result in mysql but returns false in my code

Comment: I edit my model function and write the full function

Comment: I tried this one too.but again the result is false.

Comment: then print last query and then check.